# Show that if X and Y are sequences such that X and X + Y converges, then Y converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$Let X=(x_n) -> x$
$Y=y_n$
and 
$X + Y -> l$

Now 
$|x_n - x| < ϵ/2$ for $n>=k1$
$x-(ϵ/2)<x_n<x+(ϵ/2)$ for $n>=k1$
$(ϵ/2)-x>-x_n>-x-(ϵ/2)$ for $n>=k1$
$-x-(ϵ</2)-x_n<(ϵ/2)-x$ for $n>=k1$ ---> eq 1

Also
$|x_ny_n - l| < ϵ/2$ for $n>=k2$
$l-(ϵ/2) < x_ny_n < l+(ϵ/2)$ for $n>=k2$ ---> eq 2

Let $k=max{k1,k2}$
From 1 and 2

$(l-x)-ϵ<y_n<(l-x)+ϵ$ for $n>=k$
$|y_n - (l-x)|<ϵ$ for $n>=k$
 Hence Y converges.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Note that  if $X$ converges, so is $-X$ and hence the sum $-X+(X+Y)$ converges, proving that $Y$ is convergent.

Comment: We can't comment as your format is not readable. Please improve using Mathjax or LateX